# Como separar o resultado de uma consulta mySql em agrupamentos

Tags: php, mysql

AS TABLES:

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tb_inc`
--

CREATE TABLE `tb_inc` (
  `idinc` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `codi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `origi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nomei` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emaili` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cpfi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cnpji` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nasci` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `niveri` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `generoi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `contati` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `celai` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `celbi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telai` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telbi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `codreloadi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idfunc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `operalti` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dtalti` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hralti` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idfalt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `operai` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dt_inc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hr_inc` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tb_inc`
--

INSERT INTO `tb_inc` (`idinc`, `codi`, `origi`, `nomei`, `emaili`, `cpfi`, `cnpji`, `nasci`, `niveri`, `generoi`, `contati`, `celai`, `celbi`, `telai`, `telbi`, `codreloadi`, `idfunc`, `operalti`, `dtalti`, `hralti`, `idfalt`, `operai`, `dt_inc`, `hr_inc`) VALUES
(1, '1', 'Site', 'Brendo CÃ©sar Silas', 'brendo@localhost.com', '00000000000', '', '1972-12-17', '17/12', 'M', '', '(31) 9 9908-2987', '', '', '', '6ff153749d7443d8542b6e4181a48570', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-11', '14:35', '3', 'Brendo', '2019-07-15', '12:49'),
(2, '2', 'Loja', 'Manuel santos', '', '', '89899898989898', '1980-12-31', '31/12', 'M', 'JÃºlia Alves', '', '', '', '', 'ff842aa7fdf37dd9d90d3b677f5d1a17', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-08', '10:57', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-07-15', '13:11'),
(3, '3', 'Site', 'Armando SÃ¡ de Oliveira', '', '', '', '', '', 'M', '', '', '', '', '', 'fee4b5fe8599a3eeee8394477e2c7ee4', '3', 'Brendo', '2019-08-13', '23:30', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-07', '17:34'),
(4, '4', 'Site', 'Amanda Clark', '', '', '', '', '', 'F', '', '', '', '', '', 'a3011ab63ab96c13dc697bb89298acc4', '2', 'Nexobraz', '2019-09-10', '00:28', '1', 'Infonet', '31-12-1969', '18:32'),
(5, '5', 'Site', 'Maria do Carmo', '', '000000000000', '', '1937-04-04', '04/04', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'c38b0a8eab8aee005ec8c36fd9e12bee', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-14', '23:41', '3', 'Brendo', '31-12-1969', '18:33'),
(6, '6', 'Site', 'Fausto Monteiro', '', '00000000000', '', '1953-08-22', '22/08', 'M', '', '(31) 9 8505-0000', '', '', '', '3b1a5994f2e160bcddee7a3501d9f48f', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-21', '21:22', '1', 'Infonet', '31-12-1969', '18:34'),
(7, '7', 'Site', 'JosÃ© Aparecido De Souza', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0c2dc72584d9092c3b8ada7dba6337ed', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-13', '00:02', '2', 'Nexobraz', '2019-08-07', '18:35'),
(8, '8', 'Site', 'Carlos Santana', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '135ed1983caa840be92bb839d20e5365', '2', 'Nexobraz ', '2019-08-10', '01:53', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-07', '18:40'),
(9, '9', 'Site', 'VirgÃ­nia Almeida Silva', 'virginia@localhost.com', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'a7e0c91898de2de8592f3ac618326dfb', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-07', '18:44', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-07', '18:43'),
(10, '10', 'Flayer', 'Joaquim GonÃ§alves', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'bb5fd8916a26dcc958132c3b64fa9a18', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-09', '14:36', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-09', '14:19'),
(11, '11', '', 'ClÃ¡udia Sampaio da Silva', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-11', '17:27'),
(12, '12', 'Site', 'Samira Silva Oliveira', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '4ff522f0280730c1a0f4cec21b970f67', '3', 'Brendo', '2019-08-13', '23:37', '3', 'Brendo', '2019-08-13', '23:35'),
(13, '13', '', 'Cliente Teste de ExclusÃ£o', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-24', '15:42'),
(14, '14', '', 'Clientes 2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-08-24', '15:45'),
(15, '15', 'Site', 'AntÃ´nio Carlos Fernandes Junior', 'tonho@localhost.com', '00000000000', '', '', '', 'M', '', '(31) 9 9151-0000', '', '', '', '25fb06c54d8ed04feb216fc6142c0ee3', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '02:48', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-07-18', '15:53'),
(17, '17', 'Google', 'Carlos AntÃ´nio da Silva', '', '00000000000', '', '1963-11-01', '01/11', 'M', '', '(31) 9 9762-0000', '', '', '', '22d8a80beb4f4f834a258a0671f54edd', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '03:27', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-07-04', '15:57'),
(18, '18', '', 'NatÃ¡lia Costa SalÃ©sios', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-05', '14:09'),
(19, '19', '', 'Testa Tudo', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '23:15'),
(20, '20', '', 'Teste Tudo 02', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '23:16'),
(21, '21', '', 'Teste Tudo 03', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '23:31'),
(22, '22', '', 'Clientes 04', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '23:36'),
(23, '23', '', 'Teste 05', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '23:38'),
(24, '24', '', 'Teste 06', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '23:40'),
(25, '25', '', 'Cliente 07', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '23:47'),
(26, '26', '', 'Cliente 08', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'Infonet', '2019-09-12', '23:49'),
(27, '27', '', 'Cliente 09', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'infonet', '2019-09-13', '00:27');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tb_res`
--

CREATE TABLE `tb_res` (
  `idres` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `idclir` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tpcred` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `clsfold` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dtultr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dtagdr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nsts` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nstsg` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `stsr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `obsr` text NOT NULL,
  `idfuncr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `contr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `reshis` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dt_res` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hr_res` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tb_res`
--

INSERT INTO `tb_res` (`idres`, `idclir`, `tpcred`, `clsfold`, `dtultr`, `dtagdr`, `nsts`, `nstsg`, `stsr`, `obsr`, `idfuncr`, `contr`, `reshis`, `dt_res`, `hr_res`) VALUES
(1, '4', '2', '', '2019-08-01', '2019-08-23', '4', '5', '', 'Teste do res novo 02 sofÃ¡', '1', '1', '4', '2019-09-21', '19:28'),
(2, '5', '1', 'A', '2019-08-30', '2019-09-15', '1', '4', '', 'Teste para pasta 022', '1', '3', '5', '2019-09-15', '20:47'),
(3, '17', '4', 'A', '2019-07-22', '2019-08-25', '1', '4', '', 'Aguardando migraÃ§Ã£o da proposta', '1', '', '17', '2019-09-12', '02:41'),
(4, '5', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''),
(5, '3', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''),
(6, '6', '1', '', '2019-02-23', '2019-09-03', '2', '2', '', 'Enviar solicitaÃ§Ã£o de pagamento ', '1', '1', '6', '2019-09-15', '22:02'),
(7, '6', '2', '', '2019-09-05', '2019-09-05', '4', '', '', 'teste', '1', '', '6', '2019-09-05', '14:06'),
(8, '6', '3', '', '2019-09-05', '2019-09-05', '4', '', '', 'teste 02', '1', '', '6', '2019-09-05', '14:06'),
(9, '15', '5', 'A', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-15', '6', '4', '', 'Proposta rejeitada ', '1', '', '15', '2019-09-12', '02:51'),
(10, '14', '1', '', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '4', '', '', 'saddsd', '1', '', '14', '2019-09-12', '22:51'),
(11, '13', '1', '', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '5', '', '', 'teste de exclusÃ£o', '1', '', '13', '2019-09-12', '15:19'),
(12, '19', '1', '', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '4', '', '', 'teste tudo', '1', '', '19', '2019-09-12', '23:15'),
(13, '20', '1', '', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '3', '', '', 'teste tudo 02', '1', '', '20', '2019-09-12', '23:17'),
(14, '21', '1', '', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '4', '', '', 'teste tudo 03', '1', '', '21', '2019-09-12', '23:31'),
(15, '22', '1', '', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '3', '', '', 'tsete 04', '1', '', '22', '2019-09-12', '23:37'),
(16, '23', '2', '', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '4', '4', '', 'teste 05', '1', '', '23', '2019-09-12', '23:38'),
(17, '24', '1', '', '2019-09-11', '2019-09-11', '5', '', '', 'teste 06', '1', '', '24', '2019-09-12', '23:41'),
(18, '25', '2', '', '2019-09-14', '2019-09-14', '4', '4', '', 'teste 07', '1', '', '25', '2019-09-15', '18:18'),
(19, '26', '3', '', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '4', '4', '', 'teste 08', '1', '', '26', '2019-09-15', '21:49'),
(20, '27', '5', '', '2019-09-13', '2019-09-13', '3', '', '', 'opopop', '1', '', '27', '2019-09-13', '00:28');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tb_users`
--

CREATE TABLE `tb_users` (
  `iduser` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `mac` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cel` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT 'N',
  `cidade` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uf` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `niver` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nasc` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `genero` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nivel` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT '1',
  `nivelb` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nivelc` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `niveld` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nivele` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `validation` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT '0',
  `alert` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `motivo` longtext CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `dt_log` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hr_log` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt_cad` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hr_cad` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tb_users`
--

INSERT INTO `tb_users` (`iduser`, `mac`, `login`, `nome`, `email`, `cpf`, `cnpj`, `cel`, `tel`, `senha`, `photo`, `cidade`, `uf`, `niver`, `nasc`, `genero`, `nivel`, `nivelb`, `nivelc`, `niveld`, `nivele`, `validation`, `alert`, `motivo`, `dt_log`, `hr_log`, `dt_cad`, `hr_cad`) VALUES
(1, '', 'infonet', 'Infonet', 'infonet@localhost.com', '', '', '', '', 'MTIzNDU2', 'Y', 'Belo Horizonte', 'MG', '17/12', '1972-12-17', 'M', '2', '', '', '', '', '1', 'ON', '', '2019-09-15', '17:55', '2019-01-01', '15:10'),
(2, NULL, 'nexobraz', 'Nexobraz', 'nxc@localhost.com', '', '', '', '', 'MTIzNDU2', 'Y', 'Belo Horizonte', 'MG', '17/12', '1972-12-17', 'M', '2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', 'ON', NULL, '', '05:04', '2019-04-20', '02:00'),
(3, NULL, 'brendocs', 'Brendo CÃ©sar Silas', 'brendo@localhost.com', '', '', '', '', 'MTIzNDU2', 'N', 'Belo Horizonte', 'MG', '17/12', '1972-12-17', 'M', '1', 'B', NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', '', NULL, '', '23:06', '2019-04-20', '03:05'),
(4, NULL, 'mariac', 'Maria do Carmo', 'maria@localhost.com', '', '', '', '', 'MTIzNDU2', 'N', 'Belo Horizonte', 'MG', '17/12', '1937-04-04', 'F', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', '', NULL, '2019-04-20', '03:30', '2019-04-20', '03:28');

ALTER TABLE `tb_inc`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idinc`);

ALTER TABLE `tb_res`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idres`);

ALTER TABLE `tb_users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`);

ALTER TABLE `tb_inc`
  MODIFY `idinc` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=28;

ALTER TABLE `tb_res`
  MODIFY `idres` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=21;

ALTER TABLE `tb_users`
  MODIFY `iduser` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;COMMIT;
```

A CONSULTA:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$dtHoje = date("Y-m-d");

$sqlres = "SELECT r.*, i.idinc,i.nomei,u.nome, LPAD( @a := @a + 1, 2, '0' ) 'sequencial' FROM (SELECT @a := 0) AS nada, tb_res r RIGHT JOIN tb_inc i ON r.idclir = i.idinc 
LEFT JOIN tb_users u ON r.contr = u.iduser WHERE r.nsts !='5' AND r.nsts !='2' AND r.nsts !='6' AND r.dtagdr != '' AND r.clsfold != 'A' ORDER BY r.dtagdr ASC";
$query = $conn->query($sqlres);

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rdtagdr = $row["dtagdr"];

    $seq = $row["sequencial"];
    $iidinc = $row["idinc"];
    $inomei = $row["nomei"];
    $unome = explode(' ', $row["nome"]);
    $user = array_shift($unome);

    $diferenca = date(strtotime($rdtagdr)) - date(strtotime($dtHoje));
    $timed = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));

if ($timed > 1) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger agend'>Agendado</div>"; }
if ($timed == 1) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger amanhad'>Amanhã</div>"; }
if ($timed == 0) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger emdia'>Hoje</div>"; }
if ($timed == -1) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger ontemd'>Ontem</div>"; }
if ($timed == -2 && $timed > -3) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger doisd'>Há 2 dias</div>"; }
if ($timed <= -3 && $timed >= -7) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger aguarda'>Aguardando</div>"; }
if ($timed <= -8 && $timed > -31) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger atrasa'>Atrasado</div>"; }
if ($timed <= -31) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger trintad'>Há 30+ dias</div>"; }
if ($timed <= -32) { $situacao = "<div class='box-ag-ger semove'>Sem movimento</div>"; }
```

```
<style>
.emdia { background:#6AF0FB;color:#000; }
.amanhad { background:#8CD9DD;color:#000; }
.ontemd { background:#FFFF00;color:#000; }
.doisd { background:#FFF582;color:#000; }
.aguarda { background:rgba(255,215,0, 0.8);color:#000; }
.atrasa { background:rgba(255, 1, 66, 0.5);color:#fff; }
.trintad { background:#000;color:#fff; }
.semove { background:rgba(255, 1, 66, 0.8);color:#fff; }
.agend { background:#66B3FF;color:#fff; }
.box-ag-ger { display:inline-block;padding:5px; }
</style>
```

Eu preciso que o resultado saia separado pela $SITUACAO para que fique +/- assim. Oh! e agora, quem poderá me ajudar (risos):

```
ATRASADOS__________ (Todos que se encaixarem neste if - mais de uma semana até 30 dias)
Fulano <br/>
Beltrano <br/>
Ciclano <br/>

AGUARDANDO__________ (Todos que se encaixarem neste if - de ontem para trás até 1 semana)
Fulano <br/>
Beltrano <br/>
Ciclano <br/>

HOJE__________ (Todos que se encaixarem neste if)
Fulano <br/>
Beltrano <br/>
Ciclano <br/>

AGENDADO__________ (Tudo que estiver agendado para datas futuras - a partir de amanhã)
Fulano <br/>
Beltrano <br/>
Ciclano <br/>
```

Estou enviando as tables, mas como já passou das datas, eu sempre faço um teste colocando a data do Windows em 12/09/2019, assim imprime várias situações.
Desculpem pelo "testamento" (kkkk), mas foi o jeito que encontrei de fazer a minha pergunta. Tentei um monte, mil galáxias... e não consegui agrupar nem a pau!

Obrigado meus irmããããããos

COMO ESTÁ A SAÍDA ATUALMENTE (12/09/2019)
[image: Saída atual]

Atendendo a pedidos (rsrs), eis como eu imagino rapidamente, pois fiz no Corel meio que correndo, que ficasse: (peço desculpas pela arte ruim) Obrigado! [!importante-> DATA: 12/09/2019]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os resultados estão vindo corretamente? O problema está em agrupar os resultados para exibição, é isso?

Comment: É isso mesmo amigão... exactly

Comment: Veja a imagem que adicionei de como está a saída atualmente. É isso que eu preciso separar...

Comment: Sim... A minha resposta agrupa os valores. Não era isso que você queria?

Comment: Exemplo: Dê uma olhada na imagem que postei... pois bem, os Clientes 09 e 07 são duas situações, respectivamente: "Amanhã" e "Agendado"... então, 'Como você colocaria essas duas situações no "seu" agrupamento "Agendado"?'

Comment: Uai.... eu hein... kd o código do "coelho" que tava aqui em baixo?... ué... Vou fazer uma homenagem no meu perfil procê "coelho"... depois vc olha! Abraço amigo!

Comment: Oi amigo, eu retirei a resposta pois achei que não estava ajudando. Eu realmente não entendi a pergunta direito.

Comment: Ajudou sim... martelei essas ultimas 24 horas em cima daquele seu código... isso é bom pra mim... aprendo mais... Obrigado e que Deus te ilumine!

Comment: Ah! Que bom que ajudei! Abraço!

Comment: Alguém por favor, poderia me ajudar a grupar esta consultaaaaaaa!

Comment: Insere uma imagem de como você quer o resultado final. Ficará mais fácil de visualizar... Ali em cima tem a saída de como está atualmente. Coloque abaixo uma imagem de como você gostaria que ficasse.

Comment: Ae sr. Coelho! Obrigado pela iniciativa cara...

Comment: Nada na "cartola" sr. Coelho? chuinf... (rs)

Comment: Vou da uma olhada amanhã, vamos ver... =)

Comment: oba! Valeu!!! ;)